# Не работает расширение htmltagwrap

Tags: visual-studio-code

Пользовался расширением **htmltagwrap** - выделял текст нажимал alt+w - текст оборачивался в нужный тег. Сегодня расширение перестало работать при выделении текста и нажатии alt+w
выдаёт "command 'extension.htmltagwrap' not found"
Проверил настройки горячих клавиш - всё ок.
Переустанавливал расширение - не помогло.
Очистил settings.json может там что-то не то вписал - так же эффекта нет.[image: ошибка]

Comment: А зачем вам расширение? VSCode может это делать из коробки.

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста как настроить такое поведение из коробки

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode может оборачивать в HTML теги выделенный текст. Зайдите в `keyboard shortcuts` (или же <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) и введите `editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation`, назначьте удобную вам клавишу и пользуйтесь! :)